# Mutate data to juxtapose repeat measurments

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's pretend I am measuring the distance the distance grasshoppers can jump pre- and post-treatment. This is just for fun, the real measurement could be anything, and the bigger picture is to understand the `group_by()` command.

For the statistical test I would like to run, each observation needs to have its own column, but I'm given a dataset that is not in this format...!!, and I would like to use the package `library(dplyr)` , and the command `group_by()`to shape the data for my needs, because if this were to happen again, I could make a more general code to work over other datasets :)

I am able to do this using commands, such as `filter()`, and then `cbind()`at a later step (see example below). But it also requires renaming a column.  Additionally, if I wanted to add a column, let's say "difference", to calculate the observed difference between observation 1, and observation 2, I can do this, but then I need to add another line of code (again, see example below)

It would be great to do this with less lines of code

Please see what I have tried, and let me know how I could modify the code `group by()` to work properly.

```
example_df <- data.frame( "observation" = character(0), "distance" = integer(0))
```

Assign names for our "observations", remember, in this example, it's done twice

```
variable_names <- c( "obs_1", "obs_2")
```

Assign fictitious values to y

```
w<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
x<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
y<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
z<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
```

Combine everything for this pretend exercise

```
df <- data.frame( "observation" = variable_names, "distance" = c(w,x,y,z))
attach(df)
```

Here's how I achieved the desired results for this example

```
library(dplyr)

dat = filter(df,observation=="obs_1")
dat2 = filter(df,observation=="obs_2")

names(dat2)
colnames(dat2)[2] <- "distance_2"

final <- cbind(dat,dat2)
attach(final)

final$difference <- distance-distance_2
```

I tried using the `group_by()` command, I just get an error message

```
final <- df %>% group_by(observation,distance) %>% summarise(
  Observation_1 = first(observation), distance_1 = first(distance),
  Observation_2 = last(observation), distance_2 = last(distance,difference=distance-distance_2)))
```

It would be great to get the above code to work

To make things even more "fun" :), what if more than one variable was measured.  Could I make a general code to achieve the desired results, again, without having the go over the whole `filter()` process, with `cbind()`etc..

Here's an example (expanded on the above one)

```
example_df <- data.frame( "observation" = character(0), "distance" = integer(0),"weight" = integer(0),"speed" = integer(0))


variable_names <- c( "obs_1", "obs_2")


w<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
x<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
y<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
z<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
a<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
b<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)


df <- data.frame( "observation" = variable_names, "distance" = c(w,x),"weight" = c(y,z),"speed" = c(a,b))

attach(df)

library(dplyr)

dat = filter(df,observation=="obs_1")
dat2 = filter(df,observation=="obs_2")

names(dat2)

colnames(dat2)[2] <- "distance_2"
colnames(dat2)[3] <- "weight_2"
colnames(dat2)[4] <- "speed_2"

final <- cbind(dat,dat2)

attach(final)

final$difference <- distance-distance_2
final$difference_weight <- weight-weight_2
final$difference_speed <- speed-speed_2
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You probably want `tidyr::pivot_wider()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be simple with `pivot_wider`, though I presume your data also has an `id` column to link observations somehow, so have added one here:

```r
library(tidyverse)

w<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
x<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
y<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
z<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
a<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
b<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)

variable_names <- c( "obs_1", "obs_2")
df <-
  data.frame(
    "id" = rep(1:200, each = 2),
    "observation" = variable_names,
    "distance" = c(w, x),
    "weight" = c(y, z),
    "speed" = c(a, b)
  )

df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = id,
    names_from = observation,
    values_from = distance:speed
  )

#> # A tibble: 200 x 7
#>       id distance_obs_1 distance_obs_2 weight_obs_1 weight_obs_2 speed_obs_1
#>    <int>          <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1     1           3.63           2.80         2.98       -0.795        3.58
#>  2     2           4.96           6.84         4.11        9.92         8.21
#>  3     3           4.84           7.51         6.32        3.28         9.02
#>  4     4           3.79           6.82         5.42        6.86         7.96
#>  5     5           5.48           2.84         9.56        3.27         3.55
#>  6     6           8.78           2.06         3.81        4.35         5.93
#>  7     7           8.42           4.21         3.92        4.40         9.37
#>  8     8           8.26           9.67         4.05        6.19         3.17
#>  9     9           3.80           4.47         6.58        5.38         6.09
#> 10    10           4.67           2.86         6.27        6.88         3.72
#> # ... with 190 more rows, and 1 more variable: speed_obs_2 <dbl>
```

### Follow-up

You can also tell `pivot_wider` to use a function in combining values. Here in this example I've passed `names_from = NULL` so that every column is paired up by `id`, and using the `diff` function to calculate the difference:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = id,
    names_from = NULL,
    values_from = distance:speed,
    values_fn = diff,
    names_sep = ""
  )

#> # A tibble: 200 x 4
#>       id distance weight  speed
#>    <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1   -0.828 -3.77   4.45 
#>  2     2    1.88   5.82  -1.07 
#>  3     3    2.66  -3.04  -4.31 
#>  4     4    3.03   1.45  -0.969
#>  5     5   -2.64  -6.29   5.06 
#>  6     6   -6.72   0.541 -2.24 
#>  7     7   -4.20   0.481 -5.82 
#>  8     8    1.41   2.14   3.71 
#>  9     9    0.669 -1.19  -1.14 
#> 10    10   -1.81   0.607 -2.62 
#> # ... with 190 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello

Nice, I've never heard of the ```pivot_wider()```command.  Also, for the ID column, I didn't think of adding one to the example, but of course there were be an ID associated to the datapoint.  Thanks for highlighting this. 

Your code works great! Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Yeah it's a really handy `tidyr` function! There are other similar tools but I find that `pivot_wider` a) is pretty easy to get the hang of and b) has plenty of other features you can try out when you get used to it.

Comment: Very cool!  Can it also create a column(s) of calculated differences? Such as I do manually in the example. (i.e. distance_obs_1 - distance_obs_2, etc)

Comment: Y'know what, it seems you can! I'll put an example in above!

Comment: Hey @Andy Baxter, thanks for the time spent on this. I appreciate it. Your code works great :)